# How to display one image on top of another?

Tags: dm-script

I want to add a watermark on a dm3 image and be able to specify the size and position of the watermark

```
image front := GetFrontImage()
ImageDocument imageDoc = GetFrontImageDocument()
ImageDisplay imgDisplay = ImageGetImageDisplay(front,0)

image img2 := OpenImage("WaterMark.jpg")
imageDoc.ImageDocumentAddImage( img2 )
```

However, the watermark image is not shown on image in this script.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your question. Please remember to vote on answers and accept (check-mark) answers you think solves your question best.

Comment: thanks your reply and edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the concept of *Components* better. Both *ImageDisplays* and *Annotations* are *Components*.  An *ImageDocument* is the container (to be serialized to disc) which contains one or more components, most typically an *imageDisplay* only.
All *Components* can have children, so any annotation on an image really is a annotation-component child on an ImageDisplay-component. This also goes for other images displayed on an image. You want to add an *ImageDisplay* as child of another *ImageDisplay* such as:

```c
image img:= realImage("Test",4,500,500)
img = icol
img.ShowImage()

image icon := realImage("Icon",4,100,100)
icon = iradius

// Adding icon onto parent, it will be 0/0 aligned
imageDisplay parentDisp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
imageDisplay childDisp = icon.NewImageDisplay("best")
parentDisp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd(childDisp)

// Move icon to bottom right corner. 10% (of icon size) shifted inward
number nx = 500 // x-position at which control point of component should be placed
number ny = 500 // y-position at which control point of component should be placed
number rx = 1.1 // relative x position of control point of component within component rect. (0.0=left 1.0=right)
number ry = 1.1 // relative y position of control point of component within component rect. (0.0=top 1.0=bottom)
number doH = 1  // command will shift horizontally (true/false)
number doV = 1  // command will shift vertically (true/false)
childDisp.ComponentPositionAroundPoint(nx,ny, rx,ry, doH,doV)

OKDialog("Now show move/scaling by transformation.")
// Scale and position componets on their parents.
number offsetX = -200   // x shift of component in parent's coordinate system
number offsetY = -100   // y shift of component in parent's coordinate system
number scaleX = 0.8     // x-scale (relative) of component
number scaleY = 0.8     // y-scale (relative) of component. Note: Not all components can scale x/y indepently
childDisp.ComponentTransformCoordinates(offsetX,offsetY,scaleX,scaleY)
```